# Change values in React Context from a nested class component

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I have this `userContext` file:

```
import React from 'react'

const userContext = React.createContext({ loggedInUser: {} })

export { userContext }
```

I provide correctly a value in `App`:

```
import { userContext } from './../contexts/UserContext'

class App extends Component {
           //...
    
  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.authServices
      .isLoggedIn()
      .then(response => this.setState({ loggedInUser: response.data })
      .catch(() => this.setUser(undefined))
  }

    
        return (
          <>
            <userContext.Provider value={this.state.loggedInUser}>
              <Navigation/>
            </userContext.Provider>
          </>
        )
    }
```

And can access that value in any nested component such as in `Navigation`:

```
/* ... */
<userContext.Consumer>
    {value => value && <h1>Hi! {value.username}</h1>}
</userContext.Consumer>
/* ... */
```

How can I change from these nested components such as `Navigation` the value from the `loggedInUser` property in the context?

I don't find the way to attach methods to the context and use them, for example, when user logs out in the `Navigation` component:

```
/* ... */

logOut = () => {
    this.authService
        .logout()
        .then(() => /* modify here the loggedInUser from the context */ )

/* ... */
```

Please note this is a stateful component and I need a non-Hooks solution.

Comment: Have provide a solution for you. I have also included in github project for your reference. https://github.com/emmeiwhite/Context-API. Do please rate and accept the answer. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to create a function that changes the user data and pass it in a context so child components can leverage it.

```
updateUserData = (userInfo) => {
  this.setState({ loggedInUser: userInfo })
}
```

After that you can pass that function in the context:

```
<userContext.Provider value={{
  loggedInUser: this.state.loggedInUser,
  updateUserData: this.updateUserData
}}>
  <Navigation/>
</userContext.Provider>
```

Since you are accessing context `Provider` the old way you will need to attach
the `static contextType = userContext;` on top of your class to be able to access context value like this outside of your render method:

```
const { loggedInUser, updateUserData } = this.context;
```

Now in your `logOut` access the `updateUserData` like above and pass it the new `userData`.

Here is more info about `contextType`:
https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#classcontexttype

Comment: Thank you @Nemanja! Just a final question: you say this way of accessing context Provider is the old way. The actual way which one is it? using hooks? Thank you.

Comment: I mispronounced myself, the legacy word is mostly associated with https://reactjs.org/docs/legacy-context.html.
But yeah, generally I find using context with hooks much more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your context file and set your `method` in the context file itself as shown below:

```
export const UserContext = createContext();

class UserContextProvider extends Component {
    state={
       loggedInUser: {}
    }
  /* ---Logout method here also --- */

   logOut = () => {
     this.authService
    .logout()
    .then(() => {} /* modify here the loggedInUser from the context */ )
   }
    render() {
        return (
            <UserContext.Provider value={{...state},logout:{this.logout}>
                {this.props.children}
            </UserContext.Provider>
        )
    }
}

export default UserContextProvider;
```

You also need to updated your **App.js** file by wrapping so that `{this.props.children}` works fine in context file:

```
import UserContextProvider from './userContext.js'; // import as per your path

<UserContextProvider>
  <div className="App">
      <Navigation/>
  </div>
</UserContextProvider>
```

And your `Consumer` file is modified as follows:

```
<userContext.Consumer>
   >{(context)=>{
        const {loggedInUser,logout} = context;
         return(
           <div>
             // Your JSX as per your condition
           </div>
        )


</userContext.Consumer>
```

**You can visit my github Context API Project to learn more about Context-API:**
You will learn context creation and different ways to consume the context also with and without useContext.

https://github.com/emmeiwhite/Context-API

Comment: Thank you very much Imran, but I can not pass the loggedInUser to the context from App.js as I no longer have the <userContext.Provider value={this.state.loggedInUser}>, so user never logs in the context. I have edited the question adding the method in App.js related to loggging the user in

Comment: I am not storing if the user is logged or not in the context, I am storing the full logged in user object (or undefined, when logged out) in the context

Comment: I think this can still be done. I will see it later mate. I am occupied with a problem. Mean while I have dealt with many Context API scenarios  on my github. Visit github/emmeiwhite  and search for Context-API